# Error while trying to add column in inherited view Odoo

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo

I'm trying to add a column in a existing view , I'm new with odoo  , this is my xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
  <openerp>
   <data>
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="mrp_form_view">
 <field name="name"> mrp.fleuret.form</field>
 <field name="model"> mrp.bom</field>
 <field name="type">form</field>
 <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view" />

 <field name="arch" type="xml">
  <xpath expr="page[@string='Components']/field[@name='bom_line_ids']/tree[@string='Components'/field[@name='date_stop']" position="after"> 
 <field  name="unit_price"/>
 </xpath> 
 </field>
 </record>
 </data>
 </openerp>
```

and this is my python code :

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class fleuret(osv.Model):

           _inherit = "mrp.bom.line"
           _columns = {
                       'unit_price' : fields.float('unit price'),
                       }
```

[image: parent form view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your xml code, issue was there in xpath.

You should try following,

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="mrp_form_view">
    <field name="name"> mrp.fleuret.form</field>
    <field name="model"> mrp.bom</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='bom_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='date_stop']" position="after">
            <field  name="unit_price"/>
        </xpath> 
    </field>
 </record>
```

Or you can also write xpath like that,

```
<xpath expr="//page[@string='Components']/field[@name='bom_line_ids']/tree[@string='Components']/field[@name='date_stop']" position="after">
```

Comment: thank you , it worked for me , the problem was that i didn't put // before starting my path .